# SD Card error Compute Module 3+

Tags: sd-card

I have a custom designed board using a CM3+ module and an extra sd card on GPIO 34 to 39. I used the following dtoverlay to enable the correct ALT3 functions of the pins:

```
dtoverlay=sdio,poll_once=off,gpios_34_39
```

The output of `vcdbg log msg` indicates the overlay was loaded correctly however the output of `dmesg` contains:

```
[  136.992432] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: no support for card's volts
[  136.992445] mmc1: error -22 whilst initialising SDIO card
[  137.002704] mmc1: Controller never released inhibit bit(s).
[  137.002726] mmc1: Got command interrupt 0x00030000 even though no command operation was in progress.
```

Any thoughts about what im doing wrong?